# how to Iterate over column

Tags: python

I have a one column.

```
x = [
    2352.6, 2410.26, 2443.31, 2525.78, 2506.58, 2530.69, 2530.49, 2545.01,
    2605.4, 2593, 2577.65, 2554.74, 2549.69, 2552.85, 2568.84, 2577.2,
    2693.18, 2624.95, 2543.44, 2513.28, 2487.48, 2464.89, 2469.41, 2427.94,
    2402.96, 2430.5, 2427.14, 2412.24, 2403.02, 2388.78, 2357.33, 2345.89,
    2342.52, 2361.01, 2368.46, 2366.9, 2354.42, 2348.75, 2343.49, 2426.54,
    2478.13, 2453.34, 2449.5, 2396.18, 2402.63]
```

How to create a new column which contains.

1 if next value of x is greater than present x.

(-1) if next value of x  is less than present x.

i.e. Action [ i ] = 1 if x[ i+1 ] > x[ i ]

i.e. Action [ i ] = (-1) if x[ i+1 ] < x[ i ]

```
Action = [] 
for i in range(0,len(x)):
    if x['Price'][ i+1 ] > x['Price'][ i ] :
         Action[ i ] = 1 
    elif x['Price'][ i+1 ] < x['Price'][ i ]:
              x [ i ] = -1
```

i have tried this but its not working

Comment: Please share what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a Pandas DataFrame (you didn't mention it in your question).

Then it would be as simple as the following

1. Create the dataframe from you list `x`, calling the single column `x`:

   ```
   In [1]: import pandas as pd
   In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame(x, columns=["x"])   # x is defined in your question
   ```
2. Add a new column (I call it `action`), which holds your result. As it will be either `-1` or `+1`, I fill it all with `+1` to begin with, then only change the values to `-1` where your criteria is met:

   ```
   In [3]: df["action"] = 1

   In [4]: df.head()                                                               
   Out[4]: 
            x  action
   0  2352.60     1
   1  2410.26     1
   2  2443.31     1
   3  2525.78     1
   4  2506.58     1
   ```
3. Use the `diff()` method to find the difference between each row of `x`. If the difference is less that zero, we can make `action` equal to `-1`.

   ```
   In [5]: df.action[df.x.diff() < 0] = -1

   In [6]: df                                                                                                 
   Out[6]: 
             x  action
   0   2352.60       1
   1   2410.26       1
   2   2443.31       1
   3   2525.78       1
   4   2506.58      -1
   5   2530.69       1
   6   2530.49      -1
   ```

If you want to shift the difference *up* one row, because of your rule:

> Action [ i ] = (-1) if x[ i+1 ] < x[ i ]

Then you simply include that in the assignment part, filling the `action` column from the start index to the penultimate element:

```
In [7]: df.action[:-1] = df.action[1:]

In [8]: df.head()
Out[8]:
          x  action
0   2352.60     1.0
1   2410.26     1.0
2   2443.31     1.0
3   2525.78    -1.0
4   2506.58     1.0
5   2530.69    -1.0
```

Note that the last row will contain a value that could be wrong (you cannot know, without knowing the next value of `x`).

---

#### After edit from OP

If you want to do it in normal lists, you can do this:

```
In [9]: action = []

In [10]: for i, val in enumerate(x): 
     ...:    if i == (len(x) - 1): break 
     ...:    if x[i+1] < val: 
     ...:        action.append(-1) 
     ...:    else: 
     ...:        action.append(1) 

In [11]: action[:10]         # Look at the first ten elements                                                                                  
Out[11]: [1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1]
```

`enumerate` iterates through the *iterable* you give it (here, `x`) and also returns the index of the current element.  We need the check that we do not exceed the length of `x`, because we check `i + 1` each time, so could try to check a value one element too far in the list `x`.

Comment: i have a stock dataset which contains date, open, close, high and low columns. i want to calculate  and Create a new column 'Action' whose values are: 
1 if next day's price(Close) is greater than present day's. 
(-1) if next day's price(Close) is less than present day's. 
i.e. Action [ i ] = 1 if Close[ i+1 ] > Close[ i ] 
i.e. Action [ i ] = (-1) if Close[ i+1 ] < Close[ i ]

Comment: Then that is exactly what your question was, except instead of `x`, you are telling me you have a  column called `Close`.

Comment: yes exactly how do i calculate it

Comment: Exactly as my answer explains. Just change the variable `x` to `Close`.

Comment: @HarishKumar - please consider up-voting and marking this question as answered if it helped you find a solution.